# How can I calculate the GCD using MPIR library

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gmp

I am relatively inexperienced in using arithmetic libraries. I need to try and write some code that computes the greatest common denominator, using one of the functions in the `MPIR` library. I found several methods, and I do not understand the way they define the variables. For example: with regards to:

```
void mpz_gcd (mpz_t rop, mpz_t op1, mpz_t op2)
```

I cannot understand the variables types and how to use them. Can anyone provide me with some simple code that clarifies this to me?

Comment: Did you look at [the documentation](http://www.mpir.org/mpir-1.3.1.pdf)?

Comment: If the arbitrary digit isn't that big you could use the recursive `gcd` function which is pretty fast.

Comment: No. I want to generate random values of long bits. I looked at the tutorial but I really need an example code that works for two decimals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But can not understand the variables types.

If it's the variable *types* you're concerned with, the `mpz` one are simply arbitrary precision *integers* (as opposed to reals).

In terms of the variables themselves, `rop` is the return variable, the one that will be set to the GCD of `op1` and `op2`.

For example, here's a complete program that illustrates the use of that function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpir.h>

int main (void) {
    mpz_t a, b, c;
    mpz_init (a); mpz_init (b); mpz_init (c);

    mpz_set_str (a, "1024", 10);
    mpz_set_str (b, "768", 10);
    mpz_gcd (c, a, b);

    printf ("GCD of "); mpz_out_str (stdout, 10, a);
    printf (" and ");   mpz_out_str (stdout, 10, b);
    printf (" is ");    mpz_out_str (stdout, 10, c);
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
GCD of 1024 and 768 is 256
```

---

> I want to generate random values of long bits.

However, if (as you mention in a comment, though it's hard to see the applicability to GCD calculation) you desire a random number of 100 bits, you can use something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mpir.h>

int main (void) {
    mpz_t a;
    gmp_randstate_t rstate;

    mpz_init (a);
    gmp_randinit_default (rstate);
    gmp_randseed_ui (rstate, time (0));

    mpz_urandomb (a, rstate, 100);
    printf ("100 random bits gives: "); mpz_out_str (stdout, 10, a);
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```